# How to select either a field, if it exists or 0 inside $add operation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using the $add operator in mongoose aggregate to sum a bunch of fields.

```
{ $set: { newField: { $add: ["$fieldOne", "$fieldTwo", "$fieldThree"] } } },
```

One of those fields `fieldThree` only exists in some documents. So in the documents in which it doesn't exists, I would like to replace it with 0. How may I do so?

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      fieldThree: {
        $ifNull: [
          "$fieldThree",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      newField: {
        $add: [
          "$fieldOne",
          "$fieldTwo",
          "$fieldThree"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/L422i6DPE8k